# How can I be assured that Oracle session was closed?

Tags: java, spring, angular, oracle, session

I have an Angular project that calls an REST API on Spring. At Angular, I'm using an `Observable` class to get a Subscribe object when the API is requested:

```
 this.currentSubs =
  this.entity0.post(arg0, arg1, arg2)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      //logic here  
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      //Error logic here
    });
```

My API takes 40s-2min long to return a response and I don't have access to modify complexity or the amount of time required to complete this request. I implemented a cancel button that calls this at Angular:

```
this.currentSubs.unsubscribe();
```

And when I do cancel using this code I get this Exception at server:

```
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Since I'm using Spring's `@RestController`, `@Repository` and `StoredProcedure`, I would like how I can assure I'm closing all sessions about that REST request. Since I'm using Oracle, I could use

```
SELECT   username FROM v$session 
WHERE    username IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY username ASC;
```

But since this is a application with shared database, I'm not the only one using it. As I'm running a procedure, I know if the session is half way killed, all data uncommitted will be rolled back. I'm concerned about the amount of open sessions/connections with Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: what happens with the server when the client dies !? The Oracle connection stays alive.

Oracle has a probe process configured by SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME (in minutes). Setting a value greater than 0 (default) ensures that connections are not left open indefinitely, due to an abnormal client termination.

Maybe this could put some light on the question: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2233109200346833212.

Is IOException an warning on your log ? If not, maybe you need to intercept that exception and log some information about client disconnection !?

Comment: IOException is caught/printed by Spring HTTP Class. I discovered that no new connections are created by Spring and it continues to use the same session. Since the error handler is built into Spring classes I think your solution isn't necessary here but it's ultimate necessary where no advanced framework as Spring is used.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe an @ControllerAdvice could help.